# Azure Storage: how to read blob data and properties on a single access?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need to read blob data quickly. However it seems that [FetchAttributes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.fetchattributes.aspx) and [OpenRead()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.openread.aspx) methods each do an access to storage. My blobs are really small, so I wish I could read everything in a single access. Is that possible?

The only attribute I'm interested is [ETag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobproperties.etag.aspx). I want it to do efficient and conflict-aware updates and deletes to blob contents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-properties-metadata/) you're stuck with a 2 step process:

"Retrieving property and metadata values for a resource is a two-step process. Before you can read these values, you must explicitly fetch them on your CloudBlobContainer, CloudBlockBlob, or CloudPageBlob objects. To fetch properties and metadata synchronously, call FetchAttributes on the container or blob; to fetch them asynchronously, call BeginFetchAttributes and EndFetchAttributes."

Comment: Downvoted because this isn't fully correct - DownloadToStream / DownloadToByteArray will also fetch all the properties and all the metadata.

Comment: @Cade, I just tried to Google this, but can't find it. However I do have plenty of code that relies on this behaviour, so it certainly works at the moment :)

Comment: If you look at the [source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Blob/CloudBlob.cs]) you can follow through and see that it ultimately does call FetchAttributes. It looks like there are comments for some of the methods that officially note that FetchAttributes is called, but not for DownloadToStream specifically.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know the type of your blob and you want to download all properties, metadata, and the contents of the blob, you can directly call [DownloadToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.icloudblob.downloadtostream.aspx).

DownloadToStream internally makes a [Get Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) request, which returns blob's properties and metadata.

Comment: This doesn't avoid a call to FetchAttributes(). It's a two-step process.

Comment: Why do you need to call FetchAttributes? DownloadToStream will also get all properties.

Comment: How reliable is this? Documentation of DownloadToStream doesn't say it will also get properties. The BlobRequestOptions parameters does not have a member telling to get properties either. Is this an undocumented feature?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback about the documentation. I will follow up on that. DownloadToStream actually makes a Get Blob REST API request, which returns blob's all properties and metadata. I will update the answer with a link to Get Blob.

Comment: Two years later, the docs still don't clarify this, but I can confirm that DownloadToStream does download the properties along with the content.

Comment: Also UploadFromByteArray and UploadFromStream will set the properties and the metadata